# How handle 'SCRIPT5022: SecurityError' when access GitHub with Microsoft Edge

Tags: github, microsoft-edge

I access my GitHub repo with Microsoft Edge. But when I click button **Clone or download**, no response.

With F12 Developer Tools, I get this when refresh page:

```
SCRIPT5022: SecurityError
frameworks-b656af906df0ec252f7683ae76db8ed358bf5b309bd5781fc467ae3c1d571c2a.js (1,6939)
SCRIPT5022: timeout loading module: github-bootstrap
github-bde8ac2866c5f2506bf7395e635721b78fb421368997ded86c94168228a90f63.js (17,31583)
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRNbj.png]

There is no problem accessing git repo with IE.

Any insight would be grateful.

Comment: this issue has been reproduced on IE, solved with below: `Internet options=>  Security=> Trusted sites=> Sites=> Add(e.g. https://*giithub.com)=> Security level: Low=> Apply`. So, is there a way to set security level in Microsoft Edge just like IE? still looking..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edge don't cause the security error, but GitHub's email address verify.

Repro:

- GitHub default email address is E1,
- push code with email address E2, then cannot click the button.

Resolve:

`GitHub=> Settings=> Emails=> add email address(E2)`